# Multipart email PDF attachment blank

Tags: python, email, mime

Can anyone point out what's wrong with the below code?

I'm trying to send a multipart email with Python. I can get the email body to show up, but the PDF is showing blank.

I can get an email with just a body to work, or one with just a PDF, but together, it won't work.

```
s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
s.starttls()
s.ehlo
try:
    s.login(gmail, password)
except:
    print 'SMTPAuthenticationError'

fp = file(attachment_path)
pdfAttachment = MIMEApplication(fp.read(), _subtype = "pdf", _encoder=encoders.encode_base64)
pdfAttachment.add_header('content-disposition', 'attachment', filename = ('utf-8', '', basename(attachment_path)))
text = MIMEMultipart('alternative')

t = open(email_body_path).read()
text.attach(MIMEText(t, "plain", _charset="utf-8"))
message = MIMEMultipart('mixed')
message.attach(text)
message.attach(pdfAttachment)
message['Subject'] = 'Test multipart message'

s.sendmail(gmail, 'me@gmail.com', message.as_string())
s.close()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that you may be over complicating things. `multipart/alternative` is intended to be used for different representations of the same data, e.g. a plain text version of a message and the same message in HTML. In your case you can just create a `multipart/mixed` and attach the text and pdf messages.

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication

with open(attachment_path) as pdf_file, open(email_body_path) as text_file:
    pdf = MIMEApplication(pdf_file.read(), _subtype = 'pdf')
    pdf.add_header('content-disposition', 'attachment', filename=basename(attachment_path))
    text = MIMEText(text_file.read(), _charset='UTF-8')

msg = MIMEMultipart(_subparts=(text, pdf))
msg['Subject'] = 'Test multipart message'
```

This will create a message that looks like this:

```
>>> print msg
From nobody Tue Mar  3 16:35:45 2015
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="===============4785752000147824692=="
MIME-Version: 1.0
Subject: Test multipart message

--===============4785752000147824692==
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

VGhpcyBpcyB0aGUgZW1haWwgdGV4dCBib2R5LgpBbmQgdGhlcmUgaXMgYW4gYXR0YWNoZWQgUERG
Lgo=

--===============4785752000147824692==
Content-Type: application/pdf
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
content-disposition: attachment; filename="quickref.pdf"

JVBERi0xLjQKJcfsj6IKNiAwIG9iago8PC9MZW5ndGggNyAwIFIvRmlsdGVyIC9GbGF0ZURlY29k
ZT4+CnN0cmVhbQp4nOVbSXMctxW+T+We6xxnkkwb+3KUY9lVTizHFm1XyuUDTUk0o6Eka2Hik/56
.
.
.
--===============4785752000147824692==--
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. The problem is when you open a file in python it is read in human readable form (that is the interfacing library tries to decode the information and present it in a editable form).
But we can not read and decode pdf's in his way using python. So to attach your pdf file open it as byte readable :

```
fp = open(attachment_path,'rb')
```

Now when you do the following read you read the file in its machine readable format (as it is stored on disk, without any attempt of decoding it). This will attach your file as is into the message. This solved the problem for me. Here is the complete snippet of my file attachement code

```
attachment_path = "FILENAME.pdf"
fp = open(attachment_path,'rb')
x = fp.read()
fp.close()
fileMsg = email.mime.base.MIMEBase('application','pdf')
fileMsg.set_payload(x)
email.encoders.encode_base64(fileMsg)
fileMsg.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment;filename=FILENAME.pdf')
```

Hope this helps :)